# Batch move all files from folder to each its own subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I wish to move all files from a folder structure one step up, is this possible with batch in windows environment?

Example:

I have 4 folders

```
Folder1/subfolder1/*here are files*
Folder2/subfolder2/*here are files*
Folder3/subfolder3/*here are files*
Folder4/subfolder4/*here are files*
```

Result would be:

```
Folder1/*here are files*/subfolder1/
Folder2/*here are files*/subfolder2/
Folder3/*here are files*/subfolder3/
Folder4/*here are files*/subfolder4/
```

Is this possible? with batch? Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this Batch file at the same level of Folder1, Folder2, ...

```
@echo off

rem For each folder i.e. "Folder1", "Folder2", ...
for /D %%a in (*) do (

   rem For each subfolder in this folder i.e. "subfolder1"
   for /D %%b in ("%%a\*") do (

      rem Move the files
      move "%%b\*.*" "%%a"

   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is on a Windows machine.

In command prompt the below command will move files from **subfolder1** to **Folder1**

```
C:\Folder1\subfolder1>move *.* ..\
```

For more usage help on **move** command, use below command...

```
C:\Folder1\subfolder1>move /?
```

Thanks,
Hope this helps!

Comment: Something like this yes! But how to do it for more than 1 folder, and not have to type the exact folder paths? Thanks!

Comment: If u start /w "Folder1", & move all files within each subfolder to "Folder1" root, you will end up having more folders from moved data, & it'll continue until each folder under "Folder1" is emptied. To overcome this, in the beginning you can rename all folders & prefix an identifier. Then in a loop, if a folder is one of the initial folders, cd into it, move data to one level up. And then cd.. back to "Folder1". And continue with the loop. You can find batch scripting tutorials to do this online. Here is one such reference from wikibooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear. In the result, is `subfolder1` a subfolder of `/*here are files*/` ? What platform?

If you are just talking about moving files, on Unix, then you can do (in bash):

```
mv Folder1/*/* Folder1
```

Or, to iterate over every folder, you could do:

```
for f in *
do
  mv "$f/*/* $f"
done
```

That will empty every `subfolderX` of their contents and move it up one step.

If you only want to move files, have a look at the `find` command to filter files.

Comment: Sorry if my question was vague, i am on a windows machine, i am trying to do what you describe in the second part of your post, in batch/cmd